# How to find the free fall time of a particle starting at rest at a distance R from a mass M.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

This is in-fact a physics question but seems as how I only want to know how to treat it mathematically I thought I would ask it here(Note: this is not a homework question, I'm just studying for an exam that's in a few days):

I want to show that the free fall time ($t_{ff}$) for a body starting at rest from a radius R ,to land on a body of mass M is $t_{ff}^2=\tfrac{\pi^2}{8}(\tfrac{R^3}{GM})$.

Here's what I've done so far :

Using conservation of energy $E=\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2-\tfrac{GMm}{r}$ we know that this is conserved , so the change in kinetic enrgy is equal to the difference in potential energy $\Rightarrow \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2=\tfrac{1}{2}m\tfrac{dr}{dt}=\tfrac{Gmm}{r}-\tfrac{GMm}{R}\Rightarrow \tfrac{dr}{dt}=-\sqrt{2GM(\tfrac{1}{r}-\tfrac{1}{R})}$

So now we have a first order seperable ode

$\Rightarrow -\int^R_0(2GM(\tfrac{1}{r}-\tfrac{1}{R}))^{\tfrac{-1}{2}}dr=\int dt$

Here is my problem:

I can't figure out how to solve the integral on the right I tried substitution but it didn't work, any suggestions anyone ?

Comment: Is your body with mass $M$ a black hole? In that case, you need to account for relativistic effects. Otherwise, what is the radius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{begingroup}\begingroup\renewcommand{\dd}[1]{\,\mathrm{d}#1}$The desired answer clearly is meant for a practice in classical mechanics without relativistic effects.

Presumably the OP wants to see his/her method comes to fruition so this answer continues the approach in the question post. There exists analysis that some might deem more physical and nice (see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/308955/130136) or [that](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90722/130136)).

---

First of all, your original expression is off by a negative sign. It is true that $r$ decreases along time $t = 0$ to $t = t_{ff}$ so the derivative is negative (taking the minus square root). Accordingly, the integration limit should start at $r = R$ at $t = 0$ and ends at $r = 0$ at $t = t_{ff}$. Hence the negative sign cancels and we have an integration of positive square root from $r = 0$ to $R$.

$$\int \dd{t} = \frac1{ \sqrt{2GM} }\int^R_0 \left( \frac1r - \frac1R \right)^{\frac{-1}2} \dd{r} =  \sqrt{\frac{R}{2GM} }\int^R_0 \left( \frac{R}r - 1 \right)^{\frac{-1}2} \dd{r} $$
Upon seeing "something minus one" in the square root, one should think of $\sec^2\theta$ for the very useful $\sec^2\theta - 1 = \tan^2\theta$.

To have $\frac{R}r = \sec^2\theta$ one considers the change of variable $\theta \equiv \arccos \bigl(\sqrt{ \frac{r}R } \bigr)$, a well-defined one-to-one mapping where the lower integration limit $r = 0$ becomes $\theta = \frac{\pi}2$ and at upper $r = R$ it is $\theta = 0$. 
\begin{align}
\frac{R}r = \sec^2\theta & \implies \frac{-R}{r^2} \dd{r} = 2 \sec\theta \cdot \sec\theta\tan\theta \dd{\theta} \\
&\implies \frac{-1}R \bigl( \frac{R}r \bigr) ^2 \dd{r} = 2 \sec^2\theta\tan\theta \dd{\theta}  \\
&\implies \frac{-1}R \sec^4\theta \dd{r} = 2 \sec^2\theta\tan\theta \dd{\theta} \\
&\implies \dd{r} = -2R \cos^2\theta\tan\theta \dd{\theta}
\end{align}
Meanwhile, the integrand $\sqrt{ \frac{R}r - 1} = \tan\theta$ is the positive root by definition. Putting things together:
\begin{align}
t_{ff} = \int_{t = 0}^{t_{ff} } \dd{t} &=  \sqrt{\frac{R}{2GM} }\int^R_0 \frac1{ \sqrt{ \frac{R}r - 1} } \dd{r} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{R}{2GM} }\int_{\theta = \frac{\pi}2 }^0 \frac1{\tan\theta} (-2R)\cos^2 \theta \tan\theta \dd{\theta} \\
&= R \sqrt{\frac{R}{2GM} }\int_{\theta = 0}^{ \frac{\pi}2 } 2\cos^2\theta \dd{\theta} \\
&= R \sqrt{\frac{R}{2GM} }\int_{\theta = 0}^{ \frac{\pi}2 } \bigl( \cos(2\theta) + 1 \bigr) \dd{\theta} \\
&= R \sqrt{\frac{R}{2GM} } \frac{ \sin(2\theta) + 2\theta }2\Bigg|_{\theta = 0}^{ \frac{\pi}2 } \\
& = R \sqrt{\frac{R}{2GM} } \frac{ \pi }2
\end{align}
Squaring this elapsed-time $t_{ff}$ yields the desired expression of $t_{ff}^2$ seen in the question post.$\endgroup$

Comment: wow ! thank you for your great answer :)